# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop: Unable to determine the issue in my code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I am new to Typscript with React and I am getting this error message on my Google console Inspect element. I checked many posts over this but unable to understand what went wrong here. Can someone help to rectify the mistake in my code?

> > index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
>
> Check the render method of `PostList`. See
>
> ```
> in div (at PostList.tsx:19)
> in PostList (at pages/index.tsx:25)
> in div (at pages/index.tsx:21)
> in IndexPage (at App.tsx:68)
> in component (created by Context.Consumer)
> in Route (at App.tsx:65)
> in div (at App.tsx:64)
> in div (at App.tsx:85)
> in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
> in BrowserRouter (at App.tsx:84)
> in App (at src/index.tsx:8)
> ```

```
 export default class PostList extends React.Component <Props, Post>{
 renderPosts(){
    const posts=Object.values (this.props.posts);
    return posts.map((n)=> <div>
         <h2> <Link to= {`/posts/${n._id}`}> {n.title}</Link></h2>
         </div>);
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            { this.renderPosts() }
        </div>
    )
 }
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use key with the wrapping tag div

```
return posts.map((n, index)=> <div key={index}>
             <h2> <Link to= {`/posts/${n._id}`}> {n.title}</Link></h2>
             </div>);
```

unique keys are better, you should only use index as the last resort

```
key={n._id}
```

This is preferred.

Comment: [You shouldn't use the `index` as the `key` value.](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

Comment: Yes I have already mentioned in my answer to use them as last resort

Comment: Not even as last resort, it's useless, React already use the index if you don't provide a key.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html you should read official react docs, you will find it here

Comment: When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the item index as a key as a last resort: this is from the docs itself

Answer (score 1):

When you return html in a map function, each element should have a unique key.

Example:
`<div key={n._id}>...</div>`

You can read more about this here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do a map operation in react, the loop needs to have a unique key to identify whether it requires re-rendering during react rendering process. Read through the below link for more details [refer keys section](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)